# Read ANSI files in Web file-system-access API

Tags: javascript, utf-8, html5-filesystem, filesystem-access, file-system-access-api

I am trying to get files using file-system-access API and it works good using this code:

```
function Process_Files(files) {
    [].map.call(files, async function (file, i) {
        if (isDataFile(file.name)) {
            let fileText = await file.text();
            let filePath = await file.webkitRelativePath;
            ProcessFileContents(await fileText,await filePath);
        }
    })
}
function DirectoryChose(event) {

    let files;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();


    if (event.type === "change") {
        files = event.target.files;
    }

    if (files) {
        Process_Files(files)
    }
}

dropArea.addEventListener("change", DirectoryChose);
```

the problem is when we have an ANSI encoded file then the German Characters like Ö, Ü, and Ä become �
while it works perfect with UTF-8 encoded files.

I couldn't find anyway to read files using `file.text()` in ANSI code

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `FileReader()` API with the correct encoding. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText#parameters) for details. For example, you could read the data as below:

```js
// fileOrBlob is a File or a Blob :-) 
const fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.readAsText(fileOrBlob, 'windows-1252');
```

The only thing to note is that you need to know the encoding beforehand. If you don't specify an encoding, UTF-8 is assumed.